# How are operating system animations displayed (concurrency)?

Tags: animation

How are operating system animations displayed (concurrency)?

E.g. window resizing.

I've particularly always wondered about the concurrency aspect of it. Since the OS has to run many many things simultaneously. But animations are often sequential, which means that the frames must be run one after another, and cannot be e.g. interleaved between threads. Or perhaps some parts of animations can? E.g. if the animation requires computation of shading and stuff.

What about when an animation plays and the user does something on the screen while the animation is still running?

Comment: [Hint: Software Engineering.SE... expect research before asking](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7826/31260)

Comment: Your question presumes that the entire window must be redrawn entirely without interruption, or that the redraw takes a non-trivial amount of time.  Neither of those things is necessarily true.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's just that since some things in the computer operate very fast, then in order to get smooth animations, then there are probably some tricks. E.g. perhaps "playing" with the refresh rate of monitors, which would allows "smooth transition", even if the animation process wouldn't be continuous. But it's perceived as occurring "simultaneously".

Comment: Modern computers generally have at least two cores.  What prevents the OS from using one core to draw graphics while the other goes about its business doing something else?  You also haven't considered the nature of modern graphic cards, which all have graphic accelerators that relieve the main processor of much of the heavy lifting.

Comment: @RobertHarvey But I think even Mac OS Classic had animations.

Comment: Mac OS classic animations froze occasionally, IIRC.

Comment: This question is not "too broad", it is quite easy to answer if you know how these things work. If you do not know how this works it will be hard to find references because you will not know what to look/search for. So I would not easily consider this question inappropriate for the site.

Comment: Do you have any examples of "animations are sequential" and "do something while animation is running"? I can't imagine what you are talking about.

Comment: The part that you seem to be missing is that smooth animations don't require uninterrupted computation. E.g. even if we want 60 fps that means one frame every 16.7ms. On my system the scheduler timeslices are between 18ms and 2.25ms long and has multiple cores. The CPU time needed to draw typical animations is minimal since (nowadays) most of it is handled by the GPU. So the animation process can draw its frame, tell the scheduler when it would like to wake up again, and go to sleep until then. The scheduler will likely be able to satisfy that request (since 16.7 > 2.25).

Answer (score 4):

Window resizing/dragging is triggered by mouse events, which are ultimately initiated by hardware. The events get queued and the UI thread is dedicated to monitoring that queue and responding to anything read from that queue. So even in a single core scenario this should not take too long. It may lag a couple of milliseconds if the system is busy but you would not be likely to notice that.

Animations are controlled by timers. A timer will elapse after a preset period, at which moment a number of scenarios may unroll. The timer again would be hardware based, although there may be a bit of counting involved on a (OS) software level as well. The point is that timers are cheap where the CPU workload is concerned, they hardly claim any CPU processing. When the timer elapses, the next picture in the animation will be drawn much like the window that is being dragged. It may be an event handler in the UI determining what picture is to be drawn next, it may also be a thread being signaled (woken up), that thread selecting the next picture and triggering a Repaint event, without the UI thread knowing what it is drawing. There are a number of ways to implement this.

> What about when an animation plays and the user does something on the
>   screen while the animation is still running?

The only time the system is actually working on the animation is when the picture changes. That would be "hardly ever".

Answer (score 2):

What you are talking actually was problem in the past. Back then, PCs had limited CPU time and graphics rendering was expensive. This is why, if you look at screenshots of windows, they are extremely simple. If the graphics was more complicated, you could easily achieve "resizing artifacts" if size changed too rapidly. This was caused simply by not rendering after every change, but only sometimes.

Modern computers have tons of processing power. Especially GPU, which is optimized for graphics rendering. So it is acceptable to render every change and still have tons of power to do all other things.